# Python - Requests status code no funciona bien en "For"

Tags: python, python-requests

Iré al grano: Estoy haciendo un script el cual coge una lista de usuarios de un .txt y comprueba si existe alguien en la plataforma de instagram que esté usando ese usuario. Simplemente eso.
He estado haciendo pruebas desde la consola de Python y si hago una peticion a instagram/usuarioquenoexiste devuelve el código 404, pero si el usuario existe,el 200.
Sin embargo al implementar esto dentro de un "for" para leer los usuarios del .txt, dan todos como que no existen, cuando no debería.(los he comprobado manualmente)

```py
import requests



f = open("users.txt","r+")
for username in f.readlines():
    user=username.strip("\n")
    url="https://www.instagram.com/"+username
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print (username+"  COGIDO")
    elif r.status_code == 404:
        print (username+"  DISPONIBLE")
    else:
        print (username+"   OTRO ERROR")
```

Answer (score 0):

He probado tu código y funciona bien, probablemente tengas un problema con tu `.txt`. He intentado de la siguiente manera, solo cambié tu archivo por una lista y agregué una linea de `BeautifulSoup` para ver el `title` de la respuesta:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

listas = ['python.learning','leomessi','cristiano','neymarjr']

for username in listas:
    user=username.strip("\n")
    url="https://www.instagram.com/"+username
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print (username+"  COGIDO")
        print(BeautifulSoup(r.text).find('title').text)

    elif r.status_code == 404:
        print (username+"  DISPONIBLE")
    else:
        print (username+"   OTRO ERROR")
```

Y el output es:

```
python.learning  COGIDO

Python Learning (@python.learning) • Instagram photos and videos

leomessi  COGIDO

Leo Messi (@leomessi) • Instagram photos and videos

cristiano  COGIDO

Cristiano Ronaldo (@cristiano) • Instagram photos and videos

neymarjr  COGIDO

ene10ta Érre   neymarjr (@neymarjr) • Instagram photos and videos
```

Si puedes, intenta subir un fragmento del `.txt`

Comment: Esta es la lista la cual me sigue dando error...                                 leomessi
neymarjr
hjdr1kl
jhkfd1k1

Comment: Podrías compartir el error que te arroja?

Comment: No me arroja un comentario, si no que la salida no es correcta.Aquí va:              leomessi
  DISPONIBLE
neymarjr
  DISPONIBLE
hjdr1kl
  DISPONIBLE
jhkfd1k1  DISPONIBLE